# Got Error while installing pytq5 with pip: Encountered error while generating package metadata. ( this operations is performing on Mac OS )

Tags: pyqt5, pyqt6, qt-design-studio

** when running command pip install PyQt5==5.15.5**

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Im expecting when I'm trying to run Pyqt it should run without error

Comment: Please provide more details to understand your question, most importantly your environment and OS version. Also, take your time to follow the [tour] and read [ask].